# A minimal virtual unix shell environment as a library for games

Tags: shell, posix, programming, games

I've played a few games in the past that had somewhat unix-like shell environments, but which were clearly missing major portions of the system because the developer had simply not bothered to implement the rest.

I make games occasionally in my free time, and I would love to use an actual full virtual unix system within one or two, so as to add some depth and realism to that aspect of them.

I've been looking around for something that I could use to run these, and I have yet to find anything. Do any of you know of libraries I could use to emulate this, or at least resources on what exactly I would need to implement if I need to make it myself?

Thanks.